# honda accord 2000 lx valve chatter

Tags: honda, accord, belt, timing, valve-timing

Timing belt was replaced and now there is a noticeable valve noise at 1600-1900 RPM.  No noise at idle.  Once you hit 2000 RPM and above no noise.  Power is good across RPM band.

Checked valve clearance, nothing too far out of spec, a couple a little tight, but on the edge of the tolerances, so .009-.011 is specified a couple are .009. Where .011-.013 is specified, a couple are .011. (in.)

Noise is present even in low load conditions on level ground, if you press the gas and get into 1600-1900 RPM range you get some noise.

Noise is gone or much reduced when engine is cold.

A recent basic tune up was done, plugs, wires, cap, rotor, clean TB, air filter.

Tension on the timing belt seems reasonable, perhaps a tad loose, but there is no spec for the deflection that I know of, and following the official service manual for loosening the adjuster nut and moving counter clockwise 3 teeth on the cam sprocket was done to no effect.

What could it be?  Is it something to do with VTEC? at 1600 RPM? some connector or oil orifice malfunctioning?

Is it simple pre-ignition? The tune up seems solid and power is good there is no specific high-load or high temp knocking I can detect.

Should I try higher octane?  There is no need for that in the 2.3L 4 Cyl right? The compression ratio just doesn't need it...

2000 Honda Accord stock, no modifications, 111000 miles.

Comment: There wasn't any noise prior to the belt replacement?

Comment: I would check that the cam pulley bolt is tight.

Comment: It's just hard to say.  I remember some noise before the belt replacement, but I decided that that was cold start piston slap, and a little bit of kind of transmission torque converter ... like 'overrun'. or 'precess'  you could hear when you coast.  But NOW, it's just like clackity clackity clack, right in 1600-1900 RPM.

Comment: @FredWilson That seems unlikely.  The car hasn't been altered from the manufacturer.  Why would the timing belt replacement tech do anything to the prevailing torque on the cam pulley bolt?  I guess it could be that ; I would think that something like that would cause so many major major power problems  and starting problems.

Comment: @AndyzSmith  Two possible scenarios. If the cam seal was replaced it may not have been fully tightened.  And, if the cam seal was not replaced the tech may have used that bolt to turn the cam and unknowingly loosened it. I have seen both happen in the shop. The pulley is keyed so it runs fine until it comes off.

Comment: You need to go back and check your cam timing. It seams to me if it were one tooth off, you could be experiencing the same types of sound.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It's really hard for me to do that.  I'd have to take the crank pulley off.  It is putting out SO much power at 2000-5000 RPM and idling so smoothly it just CANT be that.

Comment: It's obviously your choice. If nothing else pans out, you really need to consider this something which needs to be checked. An engine can still run and run fairly good with a single tooth off. If it wasn't making the noise before, look at what maintenance was done and view that as the prime suspect.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Ok, thanks for you help on this.  I'm really looking for some kind of somewhat well known problem that has those exact symptoms so I don't have to do some more possibly expensive diagnosis like having somebody with an impact spin that crank bolt off.

Comment: Make sure the crank pulley bolt is tight. They will make a rattle noise at odd rpm's. Also make sure the woodruff key is in place as well.